# Need to update the value of a column in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I need to negate the value of a column for all the rows in a column. I am trying to do so using the following query, but it is not updating any Row:

```
sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ SQL_TABLE_NAME + " SET "+ COL_1 +" = " + "-"+COL_1  , null);
```

Where COL-1 = col_1, which is of type integer in the table.

--Twinks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could Multiply the column by -1

```
 Update SQL_TABLE_NAME Set COL_1 = COL_1 * -1
```

Mind you saying that, your query format works for me;

```
 Update tPerson Set Age = -Age
```

If I were you I'd create a string and set your query to that so you can check it's being set as you expect:

```
 String sql = "UPDATE "+ SQL_TABLE_NAME + " SET "+ COL_1 +" = " + "-" + COL_1;
 sqliteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null); //breakpoint here, and check sql var
```

Does your SQL_TABLE_NAME have a space in it?  Try wrapping it in square brackets, and perhaps the same with your column name.

Edit:

I would recommend updating primary keys to be negative, but to accomplish this you could do something like this:

```
 SET IDENTITY_INSERT Person ON

 Insert Into Person ([Id], [Name], [Age])
 Select -[Id], [Name], [Age] From Person

 SET IDENTITY_INSERT Person OFF
```

(but this will duplicate your table, you might want to shove the data into a temp table)  - however I think this is a horrible solution.  I'd try and find a way to restructure your table schema so it isn't the primary key.

Comment: the mCount is coming out to be -1 after i execute the query. Table and column name do not have space, they have _ to make it meaningful

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that COL_1 is a primary key.. In case if that affects

Comment: @help I'd take a look at this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473215/negative-primary-keys)

Answer (score 2):

```
sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ SQL_TABLE_NAME + " SET "+ COL_1 +" = " + "-1*"+COL_1 , null);
```

OR

```
sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ SQL_TABLE_NAME + " SET "+ COL_1 +" = " + "0-"+COL_1 , null);
```

----EDIT1-----

```
sqliteDatabase.rawQuery("UPDATE "+ SQL_TABLE_NAME + " SET `"+ COL_1 +"` = " + "(`"+COL_1 +"` * -1)", null);
```

Comment: I am not sure about the syntax I used. But, I think you know the syntax and also got the idea.

Comment: out of curiosity, what is your table name and the specific column name?

Comment: Even I am a newbie , So not sure what else should i try :(

Comment: the don't have space they are like test_name

Comment: what is the result? Are you getting any error? Are you sure you have correct values for SQL_TABLE_NAME and COL_1 variables?

I have added a new version in my answer. You may give that a try (EDIT1)