# How to update an entire column in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need to update the value of a column in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5416836/need-to-update-the-value-of-a-column-in-sqlite)

Hi all I have 5 records in my SQLite data base table for my android application. The values are 5,25,15,25,25. Now i want to update my entire column with 50. For example 5+50=55 and do like the for all the values. I don't know how to write update query. Can anybody tell me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Google" can tell you "How to write UPDATE query".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET column=column+50;
```

This should help you: It updates the values of all rows by adding 50 to the column. If you want something else (your question is not that clear), then please update your question and explain further.