# Alter entries of Primary key in table to match number of rows from COUNT Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, primary-key, postgresql-9.2

We have the definition of the table below

```sql
CREATE TABLE Log
(
    LogId             serial      not null,
    JobId             integer     not null,
    Time              timestamp   without time zone,
    LogText           text        not null,
    primary key (LogId)
);
create index log_name_idx on Log (JobId);
```

The LogId had reached its max value for serial (2bilion)
We had to manually delete older entries and vacuum the table because we were getting the following error from the PostgreSQL logs

> ```
> ##ERROR:  integer out of range
> ##STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO Log (JobId, Time, LogText) VALUES .....
> ```

The integer is referring the LogId  as it had reached max positive integer/serial4 value of 2,147,483,647.

Now we have the following problem:
The latest entry of the logid column, which also is the primary key is at max (2,147,483,647).
We would like to recreate the entries of the primary key column so that is matches the number of rows of this table. That number is 953,811,856. Still big, but we could automate the process of deleting and vacuuming the table if this is resolved.

As after the delete and vacuum, almost half of the entries were removed along with their matching primary key, we would like to "re-align" if you will, the primary key with the rest of the remaining values of the table, meaning that we want the oldest remaining entry on the table to have the number 1 on their LogID field and increment that to the latest row entry, reaching 953811856.

Note that the LogId is serial datatype, and I don't know why the error we get from the logs is referencing an integer. Best guest because integer and serial4 have same max value.

We tried to alter the serial sequence to 1 on our test environment, and even if this works and new entries were made to the table, that will eventually create duplicate entries in the primary key, as we haven't completely deleted all prior entries from the LogId column.

```
 ** bacula=> \d log Table "public.log" 
Column | Type | Modifiers logid | integer | not null default nextval('log_logid_seq'::regclass) jobid | integer | not null time | timestamp without time zone | logtext | text | not null Indexes: "log_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (logid) "log_name_idx" btree (jobid) **
```

i dont see FK's

Note that the postgres version is 9.2 –

Comment: Do not even try this if you have any FKs referring to `current 'LogId` values. You would have to drop the FK, figure out what the new value is for each row that references old values, update the values, and then re-create the FKs. That would be a long, slow, error prone process; and during the process you loose data integrity. Best option just switch to `bigint` for your key  as @Zegarek shows.

Comment: What is the (1 specific researched non-duplicate) question?

Comment: Do not do it that way. As @Belayer comments, changing the ID (i.e. identity) of an existing row is a horrible idea. It is the same as saying "Rufus, you have been a dog until now but from now on you are a cat".

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. [ask] [Help] [meta] [meta.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `bigserial`/`bigint` - that'll get your limit up to `9223372036854775807`. [Demo:](https://dbfiddle.uk/JK7ij9WI)

```sql
alter table log alter column LogId type bigint;
select pg_get_serial_sequence('public.log','logid');
alter sequence public.log_logid_seq as bigint;
```

Better yet, switch to [`bigint generated by default as identity`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARMS-GENERATED-IDENTITY): [demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/9ChFqnCo)

```sql
alter table log alter column LogId type bigint;
alter table log alter column LogId drop default;
alter table log alter column LogId 
  add generated by default as identity;
```

In contrast to changing the type entirely or adding another column to build a multi-column primary key, nice thing about this here is that all foreign key columns pointing at this table remain intact. You can look them up and switch to bigint in another step.

In version 9.2 (detail added to context later) [`alter sequence...set` wasn't implemented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createsequence.html), but since sequences were all `bigint` by default, it's enough to just alter the column type. [Demo in 9.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/EVHv5JR3):

```sql
alter table log alter column LogId type bigint;
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.log','logid'),
              (select max(LogId)+1 from Log));
```

And that's it. The sequence will just continue providing new id's without any further intervention.

---

> Best guess because integer and serial4 have same max value.

[Specifying type `serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) in table definition just means `int` that you want Postgres to create and maintain a sequence for - it's not *really* a different type, so your guess was exactly right. It's a similar situation for `bigserial`: same thing but with `bigint`.

---

> we would like to "re-align"

The idea to periodically clean up, `vacuum`, compact, re-number and rewind the sequence sounds risky because it'll have to cascade over references everywhere. Plus, it's a lot of work and a lot of stress on the db, none of which you really need. Any outside references or internal weak links (columns used to hold foreign keys but without a `references` constraint in place) would break after the re-numbering. Switching to `bigint`, you can keep all your identifiers and all references to them, intact.

---

Technically, you can actually double your mileage with both `int` and `bigint` (and `smallint`) if you instruct the underlying sequence to start from the real bottom of the range, `-2147483648` instead of `1`. `Serial`-type columns don't offer any sequence-configuring clauses in `create table` to allow that on setup, identity columns do:

```sql
create table test(
    id bigint primary key 
        generated by default as identity (minvalue -9223372036854775807
                                          start with -9223372036854775807)
);
```

And both [`indentity`](https://dbfiddle.uk/JMowpSMv) and [`serial`](https://dbfiddle.uk/DskH8mLk) allow the sequence to be altered to do that later, after creating. [Expect to raise some eyebrows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8927761/5298879) if you try to show it to someone or tell anyone it's the new normal they have to work with.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are still entries on LogId column .This may give the privildge of doybling the ammount of entries but eventually  we will reach the already existing enties on the column . At least i thin so. Vacumming the table doesnt seem to fix the issue as well.

Comment: @billsaplam I do: if you look at the demo's, I'm restarting the `identity` from where the current `max(logid)` was. In the first approach, just switching the `serial` column and its underlying sequence to `bigint`, that sequence keeps its current position, so the restart isn't required.

Comment: The last command doenst seem to work on both demos. I have postgres v9.2 on centos. Maybe this affects them?
alter sequence public.log_logid_seq as bigint; this one
and this one add generated by default as identity;

Comment: [9.2 has been out of support for 7 years now](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). It would be nice to open the question with that :)

Comment: i know. But the program that uses the database is compatible only with this version.So i guess more kung fu is needed

Comment: @billsaplam The `as type` clause wasn't implemented in 9.2 but the sequences were `bigint` by default back then: [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/sql-createsequence.html). So this holds: you can just change the column type to `bigint` and let the sequence continue running. [Here's the first demo downgraded to 9.3](https://dbfiddle.uk/OB6JdGgE) (that's as far back as db<>fiddle goes).

Comment: as far as i understand these are the command i need to run from the db<>fiddel example.As i cant find any other tables referencing this one.

alter table log alter column LogId type bigint;
select pg_get_serial_sequence('public.log','logid');

and check the value

select currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.log','logid'));

i will test on test db now

Comment: i get this error now
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "log_pkey"

Comment: This hapens when trying to insert to the table

Comment: @billsaplam `alter table log alter column LogId type bigint; select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('public.log','logid'),(select max(LogId)+1 from Log));` is all you need: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/VPIWkA9w)

Comment: Running in test now.what about the index. Should this be recreated?

Comment: If you already have `primary key` on `LogId`, you already have an index. You can `reindex table Log;` if you want to *refresh it*, but normally routine autovacuum and normal traffic on the table will sort it out on their own. Same for `log_name_idx on Log (JobId)`.